# Eclipse IDE on Mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to get Eclipse 4.5.2 running on Macs with OS X 10.10.5 and Oracle Java 8u73  I got to the point where trying to start Eclipse results in

```
The JVM shared library "$JAVA_HOME/bin../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

Googling this returns a whole bunch of suggestions, none of which work.  Some say you absolutely MUST have the JDK (I'm using the JRE).  Others emphatically say the JRE is all you need.  Some suggest editing an Info.plist or another, with people responding "Yeah that worked!" right along with "That didn't work"

How do I get past this message?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Java, but I believe you need the jdk if you want to work with programming in Java. Why not just download both? It takes up like 50kb of data, might as well.

Comment: You need the JDK (which itself includes the JRE as well as the *D*evelopment*K*it). See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/264351/ says the JDK is *NOT* required, that all you need is the JRE.  I understand that may be incorrect, or outdated.  But I do not believe in just throwing more and more software at a problem until it goes away.

Comment: The JRE is all that is needed to run Eclipse. Where did you install the JRE? IIRC, a Mac has a default installation in /Library or something like that. Did you edit the eclipse.ini file in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You need the JDK because, well, to be honest Apple hates Java and has done a thorough job of screwing up what used to be the best OS for Java development.

The "you need legacy Java" message was from OS X, not Eclipse. The advice to download and install it is bad advice, but sadly nothing that Eclipse can remedy. Installing "legacy Java" just reverts your system to a VERY outdated JRE and renders much Java-based software, including Eclipse, broken.

Eclipse requires Java 7 or above (this year's release of Eclipse packages in June will require Java 8 ), so the best thing is to download JDK 1.8 (not just the JRE), install that, then point your `eclipse.ini` file to it's exact location per the instructions at the [eclipse.ini wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Oracle JDK download links change often, so it's best to Google for "JDK 8 download" and you'll find it. [Here's the page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) as it stands at the time I'm writing this.

[quoted from [this Eclipse forums message]](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1073452&goto=1718965&#msg_1718965)